# How to check my CPU usage, heap usage, thread count, process count using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heap-memory, cpu, cpu-usage

I have a multi processing program. I need to check it's CPU usage and other variables like heap memory usage and number of processes used.. number of thread used. how to do this? I just want to know how my code is effecting my system.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`psutil`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library saves a lot of work here. 
You can install it via the various methods [described on this page](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/INSTALL.rst)

---

Getting CPU usage, heap usage, thread count, and process count:

```py
import psutil
import threading


print("CPU usage", psutil.cpu_percent())
print("HEAP usage", psutil.virtual_memory())
print("Active thread count", threading.active_count())
print("Process count", len([*psutil.process_iter()]))
```